# Laravel 5.7 не находит класс middleware

Tags: laravel

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ReflectionException (-1)
Class Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\RestrictAccess does not exist

Посредник:RestrictAccess.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
//use Auth;
use App\User; 

class RestrictAccess{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next){

        if(Auth::check() && Auth::user()->isAdmin()){ 
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/login'); 
    }
}
```

Kernel.php

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ...
        'admin' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\RestrictAccess::class

    ];
```

модель User.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    // true если админ!
    public  function isAdmin(){
        return $this->admin; // а БД 1=admin
    }
}
```

роут:

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');


//Route::get('admin/products', 'admin\adminProductsController@index')->middleware('admin')->name('adminDisplayProducts');
Route::get('admin/products', ["uses" => "Admin\adminProductsController@index", "as" => "adminDisplayProducts"])->middleware('admin');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да потому что у вас не правильно путь указан для `middleware` **RestrictAccess**

Они же в одной директории как и **RestrictAccess** также и **Authenticate**

путь должен быть такой же как у **Authenticate**

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
 ...
        'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\RestrictAccess::class

    ];
```

Comment: Минутку попробую...

Comment: @user-name то что я написал исправил. опять не находит?

Comment: А почему из документации  по ларавел  вот этот пример не работает переход по названию класса?Route::get('admin/products', 'admin\adminProductsController@index')->middleware(RestrictAccess::class)->name('adminDisplayProducts');

Comment: @user-name если вопрос решил вашу проблему примите его нажав на галочку с лево от вопроса.

Comment: Большое спасибо:)